# Find $\sin x$ if $\cos x=\tan y$, $\cos y=\tan z$, $\cos z=\tan x$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\cos x=\tan y$, $\cos y=\tan z$, $\cos z=\tan x$, then find the value of $\sin x$

My reference says $\sin x=2\sin 18^\circ$, but how do I approach the problem ?

**My Attempt**
$$
\sin x=\tan x.\cos x=\tan x.\tan y
$$
$$
\tan^2z=\cos^2y=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2y}=\frac{1}{1+\cos^2x}\\
\tan^2y=\cos^2x=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2x}=\frac{1}{1+\cos^2z}
$$
I have no clue of whats the trick to solve this.

Comment: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100812174010AAlk9pP&guccounter=1